# is "System.Windows.Browser" not supported in xbox lakeview adk?

Tags: silverlight, xbox360

I'm trying to port my existing silverlight project to xbox Lakeview.

I got a compilation error saying "System.Windows.Browser" is not supported in ADK
and in Microsoft.Xbox360.Adk.targets "System.Windows.Browser.dll" is listed as the
unsupported assemblies.

I'm using APIs such as "System.Windows.Browser.HtmlPage" and
"System.Windows.Browser.HttpUtility". How can I work around it?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if you've gotten this figured out or not, but my version of the ADK I don't believe supports this namespace.  If you would like to send me yours, I'd be more than happy to lend a hand in figuring out what's causing this issue.

Comment: Where can I download the ADK? I am having a hard time finding anything about Xbox Lakeview except press releases saying its coming

Comment: @MrBell the ADK is unfortunately only available to registered Xbox 360 developers, and is accessible through the developer.xboxlive.com portal.

Answer (score 0):

LakeView is a profile of the .NET framework that is in accordance with Silverlight, but is not the same as the SL Runtime.

For instance, there is no "Browser" when running a LakeView app on your devkit.
You have a special bootstrapped container in one process that your Title will be contained within, which makes it more like a full-fledged application running in a portable OS than a Silverlight application.

What are you trying to achieve with your interaction with the HTMLPage? 
Can you redirect your HttpUtility usage to the System.Net.WebUtility?